# instrucción mov en lenguaje ensamblador

Tags: ensamblador, nasm

estoy en linux con nasm intentando mover el valor del registro `ax` al registro `eax` de esta manera:

```
mov ebx,1
mov ax,2
mov ecx,ax
```

pero me sale el error: `prueba.asm:12: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands` y quiero saber que es exactamente lo que esta mal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error se debe a que no es posible mover un registro **AX** que contiene divisiones o sea **(AH y AL)**, a un registro  extendido de 32 como es **ECX**  que no contiene una subdivisión como lo tiene **AX**, pues naturalmente siempre se trabajaba con registros de 8 movidos a registros de 16, por ejemplo:

```
mov bl,10001111b
movzx ax,bl
```

Como solución podrías realizar las siguiente operaciones:

```
    mov ebx,1
    mov eax,2
    MOV ecx,eax
//-------------------
    mov ebx,1
    mov ax,2
    MOV cx,ax
//------------------
    mov ebx,1
    mov ax,2
    MOV ecx,eax
```